# How to get the IP address of Client Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, ssi

Hi Please let me know how can i get the client IP address. I have used the following .

```
Ip = <--#echo var="REMOTE_ADDR"-->;

ip = '<%= Request.UserHostAddress>';
```

But these are not working.

Comment: What is your server side language?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript (Unless you have a server-side language, in which case it would be possible, but it wouldn't be *only* Javascript).

Comment: could you give a bit more info about your environment, both above look to be classic ASP snippets.

Comment: @SpikeX -- the question here looks like the questioner is using JScript in a Classic ASP environment, which makes this a *completely* different question than a question about getting the user's IP with client-side JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most web servers (I'm assuming you're using IIS) provide this information in the REMOTE_ADDR [Environment Variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspxl).

Your samples are trying to get at the server's variables with Classic ASP and Server Side Includes, both of which are turned off by default on modern IIS web servers. You may need to **enable classic ASP or SSI**, or use the [ServerVariables property using ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: i enable ssi and i m using ip = '<%= Request.UserHostAddress>';
 but its not showing correctly

Comment: that's the classic ASP way-- with SSI try your first example, `<--#echo var="REMOTE_ADDR"-->`

Comment: First link has rotten.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code for to get the IP Address in ASP Classic

```
<%
Dim UserIPAddress
UserIPAddress = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
If UserIPAddress = "" Then
UserIPAddress = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
End If
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ip = "<%=Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")%>";
    alert(ip);
</script>
```

Assuming this is `.asp` page you should see alert with your ip address.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with JavaScript alone, it looks to me like you're trying to use server side code on the client, that doesn't work.

The easiest, fastest (and ugliest) of doing this would be to output the IP on the s**erver side**, into a script tag on the page that's being send to the user.

No idea which language you're using on the server side, so I'll provide you some pseudo code.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">var USER_IP = ' + getRemoteAddess() + ';</script>'
```

This will introduce a global variable called `USER_IP` into the page, make sure that the code that uses this variable comes **after** the above script tag.

Comment: i wanted to alert the ip adress using javascript so i used your above code but this is ot working for me

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ip = '<%= Request.UserHostAddress %>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the IP using pure Javascript. The two solutions you provided require server-side scripting.

Comment: looks like OP's using JScript ASP classic server-side

Answer (score 0):

For the record in case anyone is looking for the PHP solution, you'd just do it like this:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
```

For example, if you were passing it in a JS array, it would look like this:

```
tr._setSomeVar(5, "Remote Address", "<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>", 9);
```